# Slideshow Not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a slideshow for the home page on my site but it doesn't seem to be working I'm using the code from [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hellosze/mU2h9/) but it doesn't slide on my site. Here is all of the code that I've added to my site:

HTML:

```
    <!-- "previous page" action -->
<a class="prev browse left"></a>

<!-- root element for scrollable -->
<div class="scrollable" id=chained>   

   <!-- root element for the items -->
   <div class="items">

      <!-- 1-5 -->
      <div>
        <img width="1000" height="500" src="http://placekitten.com/470/260" alt="" />
        <div class="caption-bkgd"></div>
        <div class="caption">Nearly 1 in 10 Kids Has ADHD</div>
      </div>

      <!-- 5-10 -->

      <div>
        <img width="1000" height="500" src="http://placekitten.com/469/260" alt="" />
        <div class="caption-bkgd"></div>
        <div class="caption hide">Nearly 2 in 10 Kids Has ADHD</div>
      </div>

      <!-- 10-15 -->
      <div>
        <img width="1000" height="500" src="http://placekitten.com/468/260" alt="" />
        <div class="caption-bkgd"></div>
        <div class="caption hide">Nearly 3 in 10 Kids Has ADHD</div>
      </div>

   </div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#chained").scrollable({circular: true, 
                          mousewheel: true,
                          onSeek: function(){
                              $('.caption').fadeIn('fast');
                          },
                          onBeforeSeek: function(){
                              $('.caption').fadeOut('fast');
                          }  
                          }).navigator().autoscroll({
    interval: 6000    
});    
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
a:active {
  outline:none;
}

:focus {
  -moz-outline-style:none;
}
/*
    root element for the scrollable.
    when scrolling occurs this element stays still.
*/
.scrollable {

    /* required settings */
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 1200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: #d9d9d9;

}

/*
    root element for scrollable items. Must be absolutely positioned
    and it should have a extremely large width to accomodate scrollable items.
    it's enough that you set the width and height for the root element and
    not for this element.
*/
.scrollable .items {
    /* this cannot be too large */
    width:20000em;
    position:absolute;
    clear:both;
    height: 260px;
}

.items div {
    float:left;
    width:470px;

}

/* single scrollable item */
.scrollable img {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#fff;
    width:470px;
    height:260px;
    position: relative;
}

.scrollable img.hover {
    background-color:#123;    
}
.scrollable .caption {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute; bottom: 12px; 
    padding-left: 18px;
    font: bold 14px Myriad Pro;
}
.scrollable .caption-bkgd {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute; bottom: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
}


/* active item */
.scrollable .active {
    border:2px solid #000;
    position:relative;
    cursor:default;
}
/* position and dimensions of the navigator */
.navi {
    margin: -26px 0 0 0;
    position: absolute; left: 400px;
    width:200px;
    height:13px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
/* NAVIGATOR */
.navi a {
    width:13px; height:13px;
    float:left;
    margin:0 4px;
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
    display:block;
}

.navi a:hover, .navi a.active  {background-color: green;}

.hide{display: none;}
```

[Here's a picture of what the slideshow looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLWv3.png)

Why does it look like this and how can I fix it?

Comment: It is hard to answer this question as it seems to work. Do you load any JS libraries on your website? Does the console log give any errors?

Comment: Works great in the fiddle for me, though it scrolls so quickly that it's basically unusable.

Comment: I just looked and this console error appears: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. It says it's on line 60 but there's nothing on line 60.

Comment: did you included> http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js?

Comment: @DanFarrell Yes, the JsFiddle works fine but it doesn't work on my site.

Comment: If you're getting "$ is not defined", then you are not correctly including jquery.  Either it's not actually being pulled in, or you're including it below the script.

Comment: I've created a JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zYbA/5/ I've used the exact same code that is used in this JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hellosze/mU2h9/ but for some reason they're different. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
To Make things work in jsFiddle:

Add jQuery as the script dependency:
[image: Adding jQuery to jsFiddle]

Add jQuerytools as another resource:
[image]

Similarly, to make things work on your page, add above mentioned scripts in the Head tag. The order matters, jQuery first and dependencies later.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</head>
```

---

From the code provided. It appears that you're simply trying to use the same slider with different sized images.

Im not familiar with `.scrollable` but it appears that you'd need to change `width` and `height` in your CSS to get desired result.

Below CSS highlights areas that needs to updated with correct `width` and `height`

For images 1000x500

```
.scrollable {
    ...
    width: 1000px;
    height:500px;
}

.scrollable .items {
    ...
    height: 500px;
}

.items div {
    ...
    width:1000px;
}

.scrollable img {
    ...
    width:1000px;
    height:500px;
}

.navi {
    ...
    width:1000px;
}
```

`...` denotes other styles left as is.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/9hcRC/

Comment: I replaced the code with your code and the slideshow looks better but it's still not sliding.